# wpf mvvm messagebox and wait for ok / cancel

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, messagebox

How can I freeze execution of one method continue on another and go back to the original when some event happens..
(I'm basically trying to replace the ugly MessageBox.Show() to a more MVVM version)

See the following example:

```
private void ButtonClickRelayAction()
{
    DoMyMethod();
}


private void DoMyMethod()  <~~ I dont want to change this method if it can be helped
{
    Logic1();                                                     
    Logic2();                                                     
    var response1 = ShowMvvmMessageBox("Hello", "Please confirm");          <~ has to be run in the UI thread
    if (response1 == "Cancel")
        return;
    ContinueLogic3();                                             
    var response2 = ShowMvvmMessageBox("Hello", "Please confirm again");    <~ has to be run in the UI thread
    if (response2 == "Cancel")
        return;
    ContinueLogic4();                                             
}

private void ShowMvvmMessageBox(string question, string caption)
{
    interactionRequest = new InteractionRequest<IConfirmation>(), myMessage, title);
    interactionRequest.Raise(new Confirmation { Content = mainText, Title = title}, SomeAction<IConfirmation>);
    // This method ends before the user has clicked the button.
    // The SomeAction<IConfirmation> delegate is a callback when the user has clicked it, how do I handle it and continue execution of DoMyMethod from where it left off?
    // Everything i've tried freezes the UI thread..
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

p.s. Feel free to pull my logic apart and be brutal.

Comment: Just an idea: Mark the ShowMvvmMessageBox-method as `async` and then `await` it at call.

Comment: I did try that, but I had to change all the method execution tree's to async, but the RelayCommand doesn't support async and it didn't seem to make much different?
I get the feeling I've not quite grasped async and await yet, maybe that is the answer..

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small example for you where you can see how you can solve your problem.

I have the following `ViewModel`

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly DialogService dialogService;

    private ICommand dummyCommand;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        dialogService = new DialogService();
    }

    public ICommand DummyCommand
    {
        get { return dummyCommand ?? (dummyCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(p => Dummy())); }
    }

    private async void Dummy()
    {
        Logic1();
        await dialogService.ShowMvvmMessageBox("Question1?", "Q1?");
        Logic2();
        await dialogService.ShowMvvmMessageBox("Question2", "Q2");
        Logic3();
    }

    private void Logic1()
    {
        // So some logic here
    }

    private void Logic2()
    {
        // So some logic here
    }

    private void Logic3()
    {
        // So some logic here
    }
}
```

And the `DialogService` looks like:

```
internal class DialogService 
{
    public async Task<bool> ShowMvvmMessageBox(string question, string caption)
    {
        bool res = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(question, caption, MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            return result == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
        });
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is definitely one way of solving it in an mvvm way, moving the messagebox to a service, it ticks all the boxes.  I suppose I wanted to go down the pure mvvm and move it into the view - hence the prism version, but with a cost to changing the implementation.
Thank you for your answer though Tomtom.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could be looking for is a Dialogue Box (or equivalent) with a Ok-Cancel button, Show it when you need to and then handle its return value. The right ViewModel instance I'm sure you would've already gotten bound to the right views with DataContext.

The idea could look like this in code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            DXDialog d = new DXDialog("Information", DialogButtons.OkCancel,true);
            PropertyGrid p = new PropertyGrid() { DataContext = vm }; // Dialog view and Main view are both bound to the same viewmodel instance here.
            d.Content = p;
            d.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            d.Owner = this;
            d.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            var result = d.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {

                this.button1.Content = vm.Customer1;

            }
            else
            {
                // write the logic for "Cancel" button click. You can revert the Datacontext to the earlier value 
                //of the ViewModel by having saved its cloned object in this same method
            }


        }


    }
```

P.S : DXDialogue is a DevExpress control. You'd need your WPF equivalent, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this very simply and MVVM-conforming: I define event in ViewModel and in View's code behind, I display MessageBox and set EventArgs parameter so ViewModel knows what was pressed in View. I am attaching method to that event in View's DataContextChanged. Another way of doing this is to use totally decoupled messaging system, but it is significantly more work.

```
Public Class GenericEventArgs(Of TEventData)
  Inherits EventArgs
  Public Sub New(Optional eventData As TEventData = Nothing)
    Me.EventData = eventData
  End Sub
  Public Property EventData As TEventData
End Class

Class MainWindow
  Private Sub Me_DataContextChanged(sender As Object, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.DataContextChanged
      Dim mainWindowVM = DirectCast(DataContext, MainWindowViewModel)
      AddHandler mainWindowVM.SavingChanges, AddressOf MainWindowViewModel_SavingChanges
  End Sub
  Private Sub MainWindowViewModel_SavingChanges(sender As Object, e As GenericEventArgs(Of Boolean?))
    If MessageBox.Show("Save changes?",
                       "Document was changed",
                       MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                       MessageBoxImage.Exclamation) = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
      e.EventData = True
    Else
      e.EventData = False
    End If
  End Sub
End Class

Class MainWindowViewModel
  Public Event SavingChanges As EventHandler(Of GenericEventArgs(Of Boolean?))
  Public Sub SaveChanges()
    Dim e As New GenericEventArgs(Of Boolean?)
    RaiseEvent SavingChanges(Me, e)
    If e.EventData = True Then
      'User want to save changes
    Else
      'User dont want to save changes
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Ondřej, I'm beginning to accept my original solution is not possible by using mvvm prism messagebox without radically altering my logic as I suspected.  I guess I wanted the moon on a stick :-)